# How to create MediaClip from MOV video file (apple prores 422 codec)?

Tags: video, uwp, media, codec

I would like to create MediaClip element from MOV type (apple prores coded) video files in a UWP app.

```
    public async Task<Result> CreateMediaClip(StorageFile sfile)
    {
        try
        {
            Clip = await Windows.Media.Editing.MediaClip.CreateFromFileAsync(sfile);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
```

The code is working with MP4 files. Is there any workaround to make it work with MOV files?

Comment: When I use the MOV file and run the code, it works well. It may be related to the decoder. So If you test the code without using this decoder, will the same problem occur?

Comment: What do you mean "decoder"? Where can I change it?
Can I set it on application level, or system level? 
I have problem with the Windows Media Player to play mov files, just doesn't recognize them, I think it is relating. (VLC player plays it well.)
Also tried to install the K-Lite codec pack, but doesn't take any changes inside the UWP app.

Comment: From this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/supported-codecs#video-codec--format-support), it doesn't seem to support the apple prores 422 encoded mov format.

Comment: By discussion, Windows does not support apple ProRes 422 codec out of the box. You will need to find a 3rd party plug-in for the Media Foundation platform if you want to play this format in the UWP MediaPlayer.